# IE innerHTML changing content?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a problem and I consider it quite BIG.

`.innerHTML` in IE produces unexpected result, literally altering the DOM content.

I'm not speaking here about the know facts which are mentioned in jQuery documentation as well, that it looses the quotes for numeric fields only, I'm speaking of totally changed element construction

Have a look at the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5g7xyux/1/) for best explanation.

Let's say we have an element which looks like:

```
<div id=container>
    bla bla bla some text
    <div class="cust_checkbox" custom-data="my_daya" style="width:16px;display:inline-block;"><div class="pip_kap" custom_ert="order"></div></div>
   more text
</div>
```

If we get the innerHTML of container we expect to have:

```
bla bla bla some text
    <div class="cust_checkbox" custom-data="my_daya" style="width:16px;display:inline-block;"><div class="pip_kap" custom_ert="order"></div></div>
   more text
```

But IE returns:

```
bla bla bla some text
    <div class="cust_checkbox" style="width: 16px; display: inline-block;" custom-data="my_daya"><div class="pip_kap" custom_ert="order"></div></div>
   more text
```

As you can see it have totally altered the construction of the cust_checkbox by replacing the order of the class, style and custom-data fields.

I have re-read the innerHTML documentation (even on MSDN website) but there is no mention of this possible behaviour.

Is this right????

This costed me a few hours, (I had some text string functions which were searching for a specific element with specific class and custom data) and as you can imagine it never worked in IE....

Comment: "Is this right?" Not sure, but it's annoying (this feature came along with IE9). Anyway, don't parse HTML with RegExp, create a temporary document fragment or element, add the `innerHTML`, and use DOM methods to parse it.

Comment: It makes a little bit sense because `custom-data` is not part of HTML, then it sort properties by name. There is no order for properties definition inside an HTML element declaration. You should not rely on `innerHTML` if you have to make tests, you should parse the DOM element to check for properties

Comment: BTW "literally altering the DOM content" is not true, it does not alter the DOM content, only the order of properties that are returned by `innerHTML`

Comment: Ok, agree that the statement of "literally altering the DOM content" is a bit exaggerated... , however if I write A B C I'm expecting to have A B C returned not B A C, mainly because there is no rule on what should be the order of an element properties, should not be altered. The whole page is in a total remake  so this issue will stop existing,  but at the moment it definitely did my heading.

Comment: If you wrote ABC you get ABC, but you wrote B$A so you get AB$. like when you define a JS object, the order of the keys does not matter. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), "On return, content contains the serialized HTML code describing all of the element's descendants." does not mean that innerHTML will return the exact same definition you used. Same when you use invalid HTML, it return a valid definition.

Comment: Ok, custom-data is not default, but if you have <input type="radio" value="yes" name="keep_curr"> it will return: <input name="keep_curr" type="radio" value="yes"> and this is static HTML not dynamically added content. To the best of my knowledge serialize does not mean or implie sort.

Comment: Serialize does not mean sort, but "describing" mean that it will return a definition that you can use to recreate this element, does not mean that it will return the same definition in the same order that you used to create this element. And it makes sense that it will describe the HTML with sorted properties

Comment: For information, [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html/#t00) is saying something about the attributes order on IE

Comment: And to finish with comments about this, only IE might allow you to compare 2 HTML elements that do not exactly have the same definition but should be equals. like `<div class="aa" style="color:red;"> == <div style="color:red;" class="aa" >`

Comment: @Hacketo if you want to add the quirksmode as an answer I will accept that. I have missed that piece of information, it is clearly mentioned there as a know quirk so I think that is the right answer.

Comment: @EmilBorconi I guess quirksmode can't be an answer as they don't really explain why in IE `innerHTML` can be implemented like that. zeroflagL covered the "issue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the DOM has been constructed the source code has no relevance whatsoever. The order of attributes has no influence on how the page is rendered neither has whitespace between them. So there's no need to keep such information.

The attributes of an element are stored in a [NamedNodeMap](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922) that is not maintained in any particular order. Chrome seems to store the attributes in the order they appear in the source code, IE sorted by name, native attributes first. But if you add an attribute at runtime IE adds it at the end.

The serialization itself is also defined in the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#html-fragment-serialization-algorithm)

> While **the exact order of attributes is UA-defined**, and may depend on factors such as the order that the attributes were given in the original markup, the sort order must be stable, such that consecutive invocations of this algorithm serialize an element's attributes in the same order. So maybe the order is the result of the IE's parsing process.

So as long as you always get the same results the behavior is correct.

Unsurprisingly you will notice the different order of the attributes in the DOM inspector of a browser as well. Example using IE:

Source code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="newComment">
```

DOM Explorer:
[image]

innerHTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="newComment" type="button" test="test">
```

Comment: Your answer does make sense till some extent, but your last statement isn't true. In DOM explorer I have the original order, but not if I get the innerHTML... so DOM explorer does not equal the innerHTML output, which I still think is wrong, the 2 should be the same.

Comment: The DOM explorer is likely preserving most of the HTML's information, since that's how it needs to represent it anyway; a bit like a JSON pretty-printer. The essential point here is that in most programming paradigms, if information is stored by unique keys, then it does not have a specific "order" to it. Languages like Java even discourage one from accessing values of a "Set" by index or in any specific order.

Comment: @EmilBorconi Take a look at my update ^^. Mind the position of the `type` attribute. I didn't say that DOM Explorer equals innerHTML, just that it differs from the source. The output may be unexpected but it's not wrong. The DOM is a data structure and has **no connection to the source code**. It doesn't know how it has been built.

Comment: @Katana314 The problem isn't so much about the order, but rather about the distinction between the DOM and HTML. Of course, almost all information will inevitably end up in the DOM, but in a different form. The DOM Explorer actually presents kind of a serialized form of the DOM, so basically HTML.

Comment: @zeroflagL. Thanks for the update, yes that will happen and I can accept that if you dynamically change the content after the page has loaded, but in my case it was a static HTML page loaded, which I needed to read back  (for stupid reasons) so I was expecting source code = DOM explorer = innerHTML but obviously not. Hacketo pointed out that this is a known quirk so I will accept that. But thanks for all your (and all others) help and useful explanations.